# Adobe Illustrator: how to reset viewing angle with Astute Graphics plugins installed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, plugin, rotate

Everything on my artboard is rotated and don't know how to fix that. I've just installed Astute Graphics plugins and after 3 hours of using Illustrator, this is happening.

[image: Rotated View]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Go to 'Windows → Directprefs' and then reset 'Constrain angle' to zero.

[image]